# How to check active and inactive status of a togglz in a jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, togglz

I want to check active and inactive status of a toggle in a jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete example.

**1. Download** togglz-jsp-x.x.x.jar and put it into the classpath of your project **OR** copy togglz.tld to /WEB-INF/tld directory.

**2. web.xml.**

```
    <jsp-config>
       <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>
                /togglz
            </taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>
                /WEB-INF/tld/togglz.tld
            </taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
```

**3. Add taglib in the jsp.**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="togglz" uri="/togglz" %>
```

**4. Test feature class.**

```
public enum TestFeatures implements Feature {
  @Label("Test togglz")
  TEST_TOGGLZ;
  public boolean isActive() {
    return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
  }
}
```

**5. test.jsp.**

```
<togglz:feature name="TEST_TOGGLZ">
  Test Toggle enabled
</togglz:feature>
<togglz:feature name="!TEST_TOGGLZ">
  Test Toggle disabled
</togglz:feature>
```